# python file operations (confuse about modes)

Tags: python, json, file, python-3.x

I'm trying to update content of file. That is what I do:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
  content = json.loads(f.read())
  f.truncate()
  content['key'] = 'new value'
  f.write(json.dumps(content))
```

What do I expect:

```
# test.txt
{'key': 'old value'}

func()

# test.txt
{'key': 'new value'}
```

But what I've got:

```
{'key': 'old value'}{'key': 'new value'}
```

P.S. I vote that this is not a duplicate.
After calling `f.read()`, I'm on the end of a file, so `f.truncate()` should erase whole file, but it isn't.

Or am I wrong ?

Comment: It is a duplicate. The answer is there if you read it well. "Truncate the file’s size. If the optional size argument is present, the file is truncated to (at most) that size. *The size defaults to the current position...*" It only removes what comes after the current file position (in this case the end of the file, so nothing).

Comment: @mweerden It is not. That question about `truncate`. What I'm asking - solution for this problem. ok, It such a big confuse for me. So how I suppose to remember content, and then erase a file?

Comment: You probably want to just do a `f.seek(0)` to reset the current position to the start of the file. Then `truncate` and `write` will do what you want.

Comment: @mweerden thank you. I'll delete question soon, in case dup. If you want. I may vote for your answer.

Comment: No need to delete it. It might still be helpful even if it is a duplicate. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate